# Solution for Long UL/LI-Based CSS Menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using [CSS Menu v2](http://qrayg.com/experiment/cssmenus/) for my website. (Or any simple vertical CSS menus.)

The problem is some of my categories have many items and this cause menus on Level 2,3,... are very long height.

One of my solutions is using some vertical scrolls like: [jQuery vScroll](http://www.tpddesign.co.uk/blog/jquery-vscroll/). But all of them have "overflow: hidden;" to their containers. So when I apply them to level 2 for instance, level 3 menus didn't show on mouseover.

Is there any solution for these long menus?
Or any ideas how to overflow them correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a CSS mega menu might be a good option - they're pretty commonplace now - but here's a [demo](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/819_megamenu/demo/index.html) from a NetTuts.

And here's the [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/) itself.

Comment: Thanks. It's a good idea. But unfortunately I have to use a vertical multi-level menu on my website... And that is a problem.

Comment: That's unfortunate because those multi-level menus are so bad for usability. Just make sure to make the target clicking area large enough so people aren't having to finesse their way into a menu choice.  Good luck!